# Why my JPA function findByCreatedDateBetween() not returning records?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Writing `JUnit` test cases for my `Sprinbg boot`(version 2.1.1-Relese) controller, I found one of my JPA functions `findByCreatedDateBetween()` is not return data, it is returning just empty List []. Where as other function `findByNumRecordsBetween()` is returning data.

I tested `findByNumRecordsBetween()` with range `9` to `11` as `findByNumRecordsBetween(9,11)`

**Controller**

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(DownloadController.class)
    public class DownloadControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        private Download download;

        @MockBean
        DownloadRepository downloadRepository;


        @Before
        public void setUp() throws ParseException {

            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date creationDate = sd.parse("2020-02-11 00:00:00");


            download = new Download();
            download.setDownloadId(1);
            download.setDownloadedUserName("hearaman");
            download.setCreatedDate(creationDate);
            download.setLocationNumber(123);
            download.setNumRecords(10);
        }

        @Test
        public void testList() throws Exception {
            List<Download> donwloadList = new ArrayList<>();
            donwloadList.add(download);

            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date fromDate = sd.parse("2020-02-10 00:00:00");
            Date toDate = sd.parse("2020-02-12 20:00:00");

            when(downloadRepository.findByCreatedDateBetween(fromDate, toDate)).thenReturn(donwloadList);
            System.out.println(donwloadList); //Returning 1 record

            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/download")
                    .param("start_date", "2020-02-10 00:00:00")
                    .param("end_date", "2020-02-12 00:00:00"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

            System.out.println("========result========");
            System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

            JSONAssert.assertEquals(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(donwloadList), result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), false);
        }

    }
```

**downloadRepository**

```java
public interface DownloadRepository extends JpaRepository<Download, Integer> {
    public List<Download> findByCreatedDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

**Download Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Download implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "download_id")
    private Integer downloadId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @Column(name = "location_number")
    private String locationNumber;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "num_records")
    private int numRecords;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Transient
    private String downloadedUserName;

    public Download() {
    }

    public Download(Integer downloadId) {
        this.downloadId = downloadId;
    }

    public Download(Integer downloadId, String locationNumber, int numRecords) {
        this.downloadId = downloadId;
        this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
        this.numRecords = numRecords;
    }

    public Integer getDownloadId() {
        return downloadId;
    }

    public void setDownloadId(Integer downloadId) {
        this.downloadId = downloadId;
    }

    public String getLocationNumber() {
        return locationNumber;
    }

    public void setLocationNumber(String locationNumber) {
        this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
    }



    public int getNumRecords() {
        return numRecords;
    }

    public void setNumRecords(int numRecords) {
        this.numRecords = numRecords;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() throws ParseException {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }


    public String getDownloadedUserName() {
        return downloadedUserName;
    }

    public void setDownloadedUserName(String downloadedUserName) {
        this.downloadedUserName = downloadedUserName;
    }




    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (downloadId != null ? downloadId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Download)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Download other = (Download) object;
            if ((this.downloadId == null && other.downloadId != null) || (this.downloadId != null && !this.downloadId.equals(other.downloadId))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{downloadId:" + downloadId + ", locationNumber:"+locationNumber+", numRecords:"+numRecords+", createdDate:"+createdDate+"}";
    }

}
```

Comment: show the Download class and your controller method

Comment: @pvpkiran added

Comment: Why shold it? You ae mocking the repository so why should it return anything?

Answer (score 0):

You configure the mock for following date range

```java
Date fromDate = sd.parse("2020-02-10 00:00:00");
Date toDate = sd.parse("2020-02-12 20:00:00"); // << 20:00
```

but perform the request using a different range that is not covered by given mock

```java
.param("start_date", "2020-02-10 00:00:00")
.param("end_date", "2020-02-12 00:00:00"))  // << 00:00
```